# Watson assistant, can not import skill. Error: Maximum dialog_nodes limit exceeded. Limit = 100

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to import a skill to IBM Watson Assistant on lite plan, which I have previously exported from lite plan account (which means that it can not contain more than 100 nodes) I counted them, there are approx. 20 nodes. And when importing I am getting this error saying:

> Maximum dialog_nodes limit exceeded. Limit = 100.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Also on a third lite plan account I managed to import it but on this one no...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this the same account (limited to 5 skills)? 
You could try to import / create the workspace / skill with a tool like https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool. Else retry in the UI.

Comment: @data_henrik first screenshot is from one account (that I am exporting the skill from), second screenshot is from another account (that does not have any skills yet and I am trying to add previously exported skill)

Comment: I believe it was an issue yesterday. Can you try reimporting your skill if it’s still happening.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty I tried today again but still with no success, getting the same error, most probably it's some IBM bug..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you first try to see how many dialog nodes are in the source workspace / skill. Check this [Watson Assistant docs page on dialog node limits](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-build#dialog-build-node-limits) for details. The dialog node limit for lite plans changed:

> The limits changed from 25,000 to 100 for Lite plans on 1 December
>   2018. Users of service instances that were created before the limit changed have until 1 June 2019 to upgrade their plan, or edit the
>   dialogs in the skills in the existing service instances to meet the
>   new limit requirements.

The instructions on that docs page provide two ways to check the number of dialog nodes. One is to add the skill to a new assistant, then click on it for details. It will show the number of trained dialog nodes. The other option is to use the API (or an SDK around it) to request a count of dialog nodes.